# Android Number sendMessage to New Number

Tags: android, sms, toggle, telephony

I have 2 classes one for Selecting Pets called SelectPetsScreen which has a button called change number .This button allows the user to change the number for the message to be sent to the new number (Device) but i my problem is i tried to make the new value of number to be the one written in the textedit

```
number=input.toString();
```

but says number cannot be resolved to a variable (but i set it to public in other class)
next try is this included in the code and still have the same number this try i created an object that calls setNumber() method still no hope :(

SelectPetsScreen.java
    package com.set.petshome;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.*;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
public class SelectPetsScreen extends Activity  {
    fishtank ii=new fishtank();
    ImageButton fButton,sButton,tButton;
      private MediaPlayer mp0,mp1;
      String value;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selectscreen);
                    //menu startup sound Code
      mp0=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.menu);             
        mp0.start();  


        //End Menu Sound Code

        //Change No. Button

       Button cn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cn);   

               cn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(SelectPetsScreen.this);
                    /*Voice
                    final MediaPlayer mp1=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.menu);             
                    mp1.start();            
                    //End Voice */
                     //Test

                    alert.setTitle("Change Number:");
                    //alert.setMessage("Message");
                    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
                    final EditText input = new EditText(SelectPetsScreen.this);
                    alert.setView(input);
                    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                      value = input.getText().toString();
                     fishtank a=new fishtank();
                     a.setNumber(value);

                      // Do something with value!





                      }
                    });

                    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                          dialog.cancel();
                        // Canceled.
                      }
                    });            
                    //End Test

                    alert.show();
                }
            });     




        //End Change No. Button



      //Button Fishtank Listener Start

        fButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

          //Listening to button event
           fButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    //Voice
                    mp1=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.menu);               
                    mp1.start();            
                    //End Voice
                    //Starting a new Intent
                    Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), fishtank.class);
                    startActivity(nextScreen);

                }
            });     
        //Button Fishtank Listener End

           //Button Cats Listener Start

            sButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

              //Listening to button event
               sButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        //Voice
                        final MediaPlayer mp1=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.menu);             
                        mp1.start();            
                        //End Voice
                        //Starting a new Intent
                        Intent nextScreen2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Csoon.class);
                        startActivity(nextScreen2);

                    }
                });     
            //Button Cats Listener End
             //Button Dogs Listener Start

                tButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);

                  //Listening to button event
                   tButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            //Voice
                            final MediaPlayer mp1=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.menu);             
                            mp1.start();            
                            //End Voice
                            //Starting a new Intent
                            Intent nextScreen3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dsoon.class);
                            startActivity(nextScreen3);

                        }
                    });     
                //Button Dogs Listener End
    }
   }
```

and here is the other class containing the method setNumber() and number variable

```
package com.set.petshome;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

    public class fishtank extends Activity {
        ToggleButton toggle1,toggle2,toggle3;
        public static Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        public String number = "+12020000000";// recipient's mobile number


        public void setNumber(String a)
        {
            number=a.toString();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.ftank);                 
                    final String[] messages = new String[]{"Feeder is On", "Feeder is OFF","LED is ON","LED is OFF","Filter is ON","Filter is OFF"};


                    final SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        final  MediaPlayer on,off;
                        //menu startup sound Code
                        on=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.on);              
                        off=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.off);           
                          //End Menu Sound Code
                    //Start toggleButton1
                            toggle1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
                            toggle1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                                    if (isChecked) {
                                        on.start();                                     
                                        sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, messages[0], null, null);

                                    } else {
                                        off.start();
                                        sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, messages[1], null, null);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            //End toggleButton1

                            //Start toggleButton2
                            toggle2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
                            toggle2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                                    if (isChecked) {
                                        on.start();
                                        sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, messages[2], null, null);
                                    } else {
                                        off.start();
                                        sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, messages[3], null, null);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            //End toggleButton2

                            //Start toggleButton3
                            toggle3 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3);
                            toggle3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                                    if (isChecked) {
                                        on.start();
                                        sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, messages[4], null, null);
                                    } else {
                                        off.start();
                                        sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, messages[5], null, null);
                                    }

                                }
                            });
                            //End toggleButton3








                }
        //Save Toggle State
        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            bundle.putBoolean("ToggleButtonState", toggle1.isChecked());
            bundle.putBoolean("ToggleButtonState2", toggle2.isChecked());
            bundle.putBoolean("ToggleButtonState3", toggle3.isChecked());

        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            toggle1.setChecked(bundle.getBoolean("ToggleButtonState"));    
            toggle2.setChecked(bundle.getBoolean("ToggleButtonState2"));
            toggle3.setChecked(bundle.getBoolean("ToggleButtonState3"));
        }
        //End Save Toggle State
        }
```

Comment: I cant really understand what you mean

Comment: i need the "number" value to be changed to the value entered by user when clicking change number :D the number variable refers to the mobile number we're sending the messages to :D